# Rails and html - style fontawesome in raw

Tags: html, css

I want to style the same icon with fontawesome, but differently in two places (different color in the menu and another on the main page)

I have icon "far fa-laugh-wink" in menu:

```
  <li class="nav-item">
    <%= link_to raw('<i class="far fa-laugh-wink"></i> funny'), posts_path, class: "nav-link" %>
  </li>
```

and on the main page:

```
<section class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="background-color: white; color: black; padding: 15px">
  <div class="jumbotron-body">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 style="color: black; font-weight: bold; font-family: Lato">
        <i class="far fa-laugh-wink"></i>
        funny
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

and styles.css.scss.rb

```
i.far.fa-laugh-wink{
background: linear-gradient(to right, #67b26f, #4ca2cd); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
background-clip: text;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
color: transparent;
}
```

In the menu I want have icon laugh wink with `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); but when I add style="color: color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); !important"`its have 2 colors :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you just want to have one icone in few different colours, here is sample and please check for correct names of your icons and version of awesome font.
//this is what you need to put into styles.scss as example;

```css
.red_colour{
  color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.blue_colour{
  color:rgba(1C,07,DF 0.5);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div>

<i class="far fa-laugh-wink"  style="color:blue;"></i>
<i class="far fa-laugh-wink blue_colour" ></i>
<i class="far fa-laugh-wink red_colour"  ></i>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: with gradient in main page from styles.scss and in the menu color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  So How can I do this? Its important asap. I hope you can help me :)

Comment: hmm so you need to use gradient colour? here is updated sample. Also if you need to use that colour as from styles.scss just create class in that file and add the color property, let me update this sample